# same code in two specialized methods

Tags: c++, dry, template-specialization, boost-serialization

I have a class with an empty template method:

```
// my method in a class
template<class U>
void save(U& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    // empty
}
```

And I have three sepcializations right after the class in the same header, but two of them have the same code:

```
template<>
void Dataset1::save(boost::archive::xml_oarchive& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Dataset0);
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_a1_);
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_b1_);
}

template<>
void Dataset1::save(boost::archive::text_oarchive& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Dataset0>(*this);
    archive & m_a1_;
    archive & m_b1_;
}

template<>
void Dataset1::save(boost::archive::binary_oarchive& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Dataset0>(*this);
    archive & m_a1_;
    archive & m_b1_;
}
```

1. What can I do to not repeat myself?
2. Is it OK to have an empty method?
3. Is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Any reason the main template doesn't have the code you need to the second two cases and you just specialize the template for the once case where the code needs to be different?

Comment: You mean I can put the redundant code into the empty method. But I'm concerned that someone could use a fourth type for U and then it maybe wouldn't compile.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to have happen.  Do you want the caller to call the function and let it compile when it is not a supported type or do you want them to get a compiler error telling them they can't use that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to just have an implementation method that those two call

```
class Dataset1 {

    ... 

private:
    template <typename T>
    void save_impl_text_binary(T& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Dataset0>(*this);
        archive & m_a1_;
        archive & m_b1_;
    }
};

template<>
void Dataset1::save(boost::archive::xml_oarchive& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Dataset0);
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_a1_);
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_b1_);
}

template<>
void Dataset1::save(boost::archive::text_oarchive& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    this->save_impl_text_binary(archive, version);
}

template<>
void Dataset1::save(boost::archive::binary_oarchive& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    this->save_impl_text_binary(archive, version);
}
```

Comment: @bais yep! fixed